# difference time classes in R

Tags: r, datetime

Lately I got more often in touch with dates in R. However, I always have the feeling I do not handle them correctly. Usually I use `strptime` to convert a certain string format to a date. Recently I encounter the `as.Date`in R. Are there any general rule which one should use? What are differences / advantages / disadvantages of the two? Maybe there are even better classes?

One thing I noticed is the following: Haveing an date as `as.Date` I can easily add days, i.e.

```
> as.Date("10-05-2014",format="%d-%m-%Y") + 1
[1] "2014-05-11"
```

simply adding one day, while

```
> strptime("10-05-2014",format="%d-%m-%Y") + 1
[1] "2014-05-10 00:00:01 CEST"
```

adds by default seconds. Maybe one can also easily add day?

Thanks for your insights

Comment: You should check out `lubridate`.

Comment: For future reference, check out `difftime` and `ISOdate`. I find those helpful when working with dates/times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick summary:

- `Date` objects are internally stored as an integer number of days from a date zero (typically 1970-01-01)
- `POSIXt` objects (either `POSIXct` or `POSIXlt`, the latter is what `strptime` creates) do something similar, but store that in seconds (very roughly speaking)

This is why adding one to `Date` objects increments by 1 day, but adding 1 to `POSIXt` objects increments by one second.

`POSIXlt` objects in particular are special because unlike `POSIXct` objects you can add other time elements:

```
ltDate <-  strptime("10-05-2014",format="%d-%m-%Y")  # produces POSIXlt object
ltDate$mday <- ltDate$mday + 1                       
ltDate
# [1] "2014-05-11"
unlist(ltDate)          # POSIXlt objects are stored as lists of date elements
#  sec   min  hour  mday   mon  year  wday  yday isdst 
#    0     0     0    11     4   114     6   129     1
```

Also, see this **[blog entry](http://www.noamross.net/blog/2014/2/10/using-times-and-dates-in-r---presentation-code.html)** for more details.

To Summarize:

- Use `Date` objects if you don't care about the time of day
- Use `POSIXlt` objects if you are going to do date arithmetic
- USE `POSIXct` objects if you care about time of day, but don't need to do complex date arithmetic (i.e. you just need to add second, hours - 3600 seconds, days - 24 * 3600 seconds, etc).

Also, as Richard points out, package `lubridate` provides tools to do some of the more complex date manipulations you would typically do with `POSIXlt` with `POSIXct` objects.  Since `POSIXct` objects are simpler and smaller, it may be preferable to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
time1 <- strptime("10-05-2014",format="%d-%m-%Y")
time1$mday <- time1$mday+1
time1
#[1] "2014-05-11 EDT"
 class(time1)
#[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt" 

 class(as.Date("10-05-2014",format="%d-%m-%Y") + 1)
#[1] "Date"
```